# Running php files from javascript on linux

Tags: javascript, php, linux, fetch

I am running fetch as a way to run php files from javascript.
Specifically, the following code is executed

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
    <title>test</title>
  </head>
  <body>
    <form name="form" id="form">
      <input type="text" id="text">
      <button type="button" onclick="push()">push</button>
    </form>

    <script>
        async function push(){
          var form = document.form;
          console.log(form.text.value);
          await fetch('test.php?text='+ form.text.value)
          .then(res=> {return res.text();})
          .then(res => {
            console.log(res);
            var result = JSON.parse(res);
            console.log(result.result);
            console.log(result.msg);
          });
        }
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

```
<?php
    if(isset($_GET['text']) && $_GET['text']!=""){
        $result = "OK";
        $msg = $_GET['text'];
    }else{
        $result = "NG";
        $msg = "message";
    }

    $result = json_encode(
        array(
            "result" => $result,
            "msg" => $msg,
        )
    );

    echo $result;
    return $result;
?>
```

This works fine on windows, but does not work on linux.
The entire php script is returned in console.log(res).
Do you know why?

The linux environment uses the following

OS:
Debian GNU/Linux 10 \n \l

PHP:
PHP 7.3.31-1~deb10u1 (cli) (built: Oct 24 2021 15:18:08) ( NTS )
Copyright (c) 1997-2018 The PHP Group
Zend Engine v3.3.31, Copyright (c) 1998-2018 Zend Technologies
with Zend OPcache v7.3.31-1~deb10u1, Copyright (c) 1999-2018, by Zend Technologies

Do I need some kind of spell to make it recognize the php file?

Comment: You have to properly set web server (usually Apache provides php support by default, but I not sure about Nginx)

Comment: What do you get if you navigate to that in the browser?

Comment: Check your httpd config file(s) and see whether handler is enabled for PHP in your linux box

Comment: @tink
Thank you for your comment.

If you view the above html in your browser, you will see a simple form with only a text box and a button.

If I enter a value in the text box and press the button
php will return the result "OK", and the value entered in the text box as a message.

The javascript just outputs the value to the console.

Comment: @Ken Lee 
Thank you for your comment.

How can I check that?

Comment: Sorry, I wasn't very clear in my question ... http://your.ip.or.dns.name/test.php?text=some.value ... what does THAT say?

Comment: @tink This means passing values from javascript to php.
The php listed at the bottom of the page is `test.php`.
For example, if you use `test.php?text=aaa`, the value of `$_GET['text']` will be aaa on the php side.

Comment: I'm aware of what it does. But if you call that page directly - does it work?

Comment: @tink Yes, it works when called directly. An array in JSON format is displayed on the standard output.
The entire php script will not be displayed as it happens when called via JavaScript.